# Convert Variable that has an integer into a String

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a variable called `val` that has a value of `5` therefore `val = 5` what I would like to accomplish is changing the value of `val` to `"5"`. How can this be done?

Comment: This would seem to be a job for `val.toString()`.

Comment: Not sure that would work I need the `"`

Comment: Then you can make sure. It's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a variant:

```js
let val = 5;
val = JSON.stringify(String(val));
console.log(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't overthink string manipulation. It is easy.

```
const str = '"' + val + '"';
```

gives a quoted string.  Why does this work? JS, when evaluating a number in a string context, converts it to its string implicitly.

On the other hand, if you have floating-point numbers you want something like this.

```
const val = 1.0/3.0;
const str = '"' + val.toFixed(2) + '"';
```

so you get `"0.33"` and not `"0.33333333333333333333333"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const val = 5
const valString = (val) => `"${val}"`
```